# JakeWharton TitlePageIndicator: How to display only half of right and left title

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I'm using JakeWharton TitlePageIndicator. The indicator has worked very find until I set the title to a little bit long string (20 characters), the center title is displayed very well but the left and the right title is too closed to the center title. Is there any way to make it just like in Google play where the left and the right title is showed only half (or a fix length)?

Thank you,

Comment: The library is open source. Maybe you dig into the code and change the title handling yourself?

Comment: @WarrenFaith: I have tried to dig into the code. I see that there is a variable mClippadding, but this variable control the padding between left title with left edge (and right title with right edge). I cannot find the variable which controls the distance between left/right title with center title. Could you please give me some clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who may have this same problem. In JakeWharton TitlePageIndicator, there is 2 method which will control the display of left and right title:

```
/**
 * Set bounds for the right textView including clip padding.
 *
 * @param curViewBound
 *            current bounds.
 * @param curViewWidth
 *            width of the view.
 */
private void clipViewOnTheRight(Rect curViewBound, float curViewWidth, int right) {
    // isShowPartOfInactiveTitles is my variable which is set default to TRUE
    if(isShowPartOfInactiveTitles){
        curViewBound.right = (int)(right + curViewWidth - 60);
        curViewBound.left = (int)(right - 60);
    }else{
        curViewBound.right = (int) (right - mClipPadding);
        curViewBound.left = (int) (curViewBound.right - curViewWidth);
    }
}

/**
 * Set bounds for the left textView including clip padding.
 *
 * @param curViewBound
 *            current bounds.
 * @param curViewWidth
 *            width of the view.
 */
private void clipViewOnTheLeft(Rect curViewBound, float curViewWidth, int left) {
    // isShowPartOfInactiveTitles is my variable which is set default to TRUE
    if(isShowPartOfInactiveTitles){
        curViewBound.left = (int)(left - curViewWidth + 60);
        curViewBound.right = (int)(left + 60);
    }else{
        curViewBound.left = (int) (left + mClipPadding);
        curViewBound.right = (int) (mClipPadding + curViewWidth);   
    }
}
```

The above code snippet will show only 60dp of left and right title. You can make this number a attribute and pass it through xml. Here I hardcoded it for easy understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to modify the library like that.
Just specify a clipPadding for the TitlePageIndicator.

Like that :

```
mIndicator.setClipPadding(-60);
```

Comment: As I replied to WarrenFaith above, the mClipPadding controls the distance between title and edges. If I set clip padding to -60, it will hide the left and the right title 60dip but what I need is to show the left and the right title only, for example, 60dip. That's why I've come to modify the library as answer below.